# General solution of differential equation: $y'+x(1-x^2)y=x \sqrt{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is my second question about this topic. First one has been solved due to your help. I am thankful for that.
$$y'+x(1-x^2)y=x\sqrt{y}$$
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried.

Comment: What do you know about linear and non linear differential equation?

Comment: Have you tried substitution $ u=\sqrt y$

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I tried that but didn't know how to substitute dy/dx according to that.

Comment: @RaulNəcəfli Check J.G's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following @MohammadRiazi-Kermani's suggestion to define $u:=\sqrt{y}$, we have $u^\prime+Pu=Q$ with $P:=\frac12x(1-x^2),\,Q:=\frac12x$. This can be solved with the integration factor method, viz. $u=R^{-1}\int RQdx$ with $R=\exp\int Pdx$. Taking $R=\exp-v^2$ with $v:=\frac{1-x^2}{2}$, $$u=-\frac12\exp v^2\int\exp-v^2dv=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}v\exp v^2+C\exp v^2$$for an integration constant $v$. In terms of the original variables,$$y=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\frac{1-x^2}{2}-C\right)^2\exp\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and while this might actually be a correct answer for question, we haven't been taught more than half of this. Particularly anything after the sentence "This can be solved with the after integration factor method" is unknown to us.

Comment: @RaulNəcəfli That's a shame, because I can't see how else you're expected to do it. For your benefit, the idea is that $$R=\exp\int Pdx\implies R^\prime=RP\implies (Ry)^\prime=RQ\implies y=R^{-1}\int RQdx.$$